# How to map HTML to PDF?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

When I have a HTML page I have styled or positioned elements and the same happens in a PDF file.

I would like to understand the mechanism behind building a PDF so I can map HTML to PDF thru Node.js / JavaScript.

I understand I need to somehow render a page so I can get positioning and size information on a page. How does the PDF positioning system work, and how can I style it? what language/API does it have?

Comment: The "Technical foundations" section of the PDF article on Wikipedia is a good place to start: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format

Comment: @Jordan indeed, just a bit overwhelming. I wonder if there could be some easyer examples of "blocks" to build a file, something like mapping a `<p>` in a certain position in the page to a block of "PDF language" and small explanation of its language/API to place that `<p>` in the PDF.

Comment: The PostScript article has a "Hello, world!" example. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript Frankly, you're jumping down a rabbit hole, here. Why not use one of the libraries that already exists? https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=html%20to%20pdf